# Android работа с кнопкой

Tags: android, случайные-числа

Подскажите, хотелось бы чтобы на кнопке выводилось рандомное значение

вот код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1;
    Random random;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        int a = random.nextInt(300);

        button1.setText(Integer.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Но приложение не работает. На телефоне выбрасывает ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Вы объявили, но не инициализировали `random`

```
random = new Random();
int a = random.nextInt(300);
```